# python parse condition as dictionary keys / pandas columns /xarray variables

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, python-xarray

I want to parse condition provided as string to filter xarray dataset.
For example, the string condition could be `filter = '(solar_zenith_angle > 50) & (latitude > -17) & (longitude > 56)'`. So for my xarray dataset `ds` containing these variables would be `filter = (ds.solar_zenith_angle > 50) & (ds.latitude > -17) & (ds.longitude > 56)`. Now my question is, how can I define a function which could convert this string filter condition to query which I can use to filter the dataset (e.g. `ds.where(filter)`)

Comment: Check if the `ast` module provides functions you can use.